# Can I disable email notifications of changes in a Google Doc via Google Apps Script?

Tags: email, google-apps-script, notifications, comments

I have a Google Form that when submitted, a Google Apps Script generates a Google Doc with the information submitted and some magic behind it. This Google Doc is emailed to various people for collaboration purposes.

Whenever someone makes a comment, I get an email notification of the comment, flooding my inbox. I know I can disable the notifications manually from the Doc, but can I disable them via Google Apps Script to avoid that manual step?

The Google Doc is created by making a copy from a template. I disabled the notification settings in the template, but those settings are not being carried over to the copy.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I have not been able to find a way to change the notification settings programmatically, it doesn't matter that the original file had the notification settings a certain way, when the file is copied the copy is a "new" file for these settings. What I can suggest is that you create a label & filter in your Gmail to handle these emails (since changing the settings manually is not a solution). There's instructions on how to build [labels here](added comments to the following document) and on how to create [filters here](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7326859?hl=en). Would this work?

Comment: Hi @AMolina, that is a very good idea, however, all comment email notifications have the same subject: [External] and there are some comments I would like to get notified on for other documents unrelated to this. I will give some though how can I make it so that these documents all have a very similar title, hence, the same subject in order to make a Filter.

Comment: You can make the filter seek messages that contain "added comments to the following document" and archive them, that would let you see them at your leisure so that you can see the ones you need and it won't clutter your inbox.